# In dotnet core 3.0 RC1 is it possible to prerender a client-side Blazor app on the server?

Tags: c#, .net-core, blazor

I've read a few articles about doing this in earlier previews but none of them works for RC1.

What I'm trying to achieve is that the first request into the URL (regardless of if it's `/` or `/about`, etc.) should have the page content rendered by the server-side application and the full markup delivered to the browser.

Once that first request is done the client-side Blazor Web Assembly app should take over.

What I have right now:

- LCBlazor.Client - the client-side Blazor app
- LCBlazor.Server - a server-side dotNet core 3 app

```cs
// MyApp.Server - Startup.cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc().AddNewtonsoftJson();
    services.AddServerSideBlazor();

    services.AddResponseCompression(opts =>
    {
        opts.MimeTypes = ResponseCompressionDefaults.MimeTypes.Concat(
            new[] { "application/octet-stream" });
    });
}

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseResponseCompression();

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseBlazorDebugging();
    }

    app.UseClientSideBlazorFiles<Client.Startup>();

    app.UseFileServer();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
        //endpoints.MapFallbackToClientSideBlazor<App>("/index.html");
    });
}
```

```html
@* LCBlazor.Server.Pages._Host.cshtml *@
@page "/"
@namespace LCBlazor.Server.Pages
@using LCBlazor.Client
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>LCBlazor Prerendered</title>
    <base href="/" />
    <link href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <app>@(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<App>(RenderMode.Server))</app>

    <script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Everything else is as-per the default blazor templates (with the RenderTree errors fixed).

The current behaviour is that the app loads, but if I disable JS in my browser I get no content which indicates that the app is still relying on the client-side for rendering.

Comment: @daniherrera different issue here. I’m trying to prerender the client side blazor web assembly app pages.

Comment: Nice, I understand now. Pre-render client side wasm via server. ok. I remove 'related' comment.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/hosting-models?view=aspnetcore-3.0#blazor-server Blazor Server hosting model still relies on browser side JavaScript, as it needs a SignalR connection to talk to the server side.

Comment: @LexLi In RC1 there is the option to pre-render the output of Blazor Server on the server such that the first request is fully rendered on the server-side. I'm trying to leverage this behaviour for the Blazor WebAssembly app by having it hosted with both methods.

There are many articles in Google that talk about different ways of doing this that apparently worked in earlier preview releases but they don't work in RC1 so my question is specifically about how to get this behaviour working in RC1

Comment: Your sentence of "there is the option to pre-render the output of Blazor Server on the server such that the first request is fully rendered on the server-side" does not invalidate what I said above. Though rendered on server side, those results won't magically jump from server side to the browser, and clearly that article I linked illustrated how browser side JavaScript/SignalR pull them down. So whatever you play with, JavaScript cannot be disabled. Even for browser side Blazor, JavaScript is still required (by design).

Comment: It doesn’t need to magically jump anywhere. The server received a request and serves up the fully rendered HTML for the path requested. The JavaScript takes over from there but the point is that the JavaScript is NOT required to serve that first rendered page.